# Passing parameters to an inline javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, session-storage

I am trying to assign a function to each button on my home page through a loop. 
When each of the first three buttons are clicked it should set an item in session storage to true (either Grass, Molluscs or Sweaters). When the bottom button is clicked, it should display all the other buttons which were clicked plus the word plants.

For example
If I click "Send me more information about Grass"
And then click "Things you want more information about"
The last button should then display "Grass Plants"
If I then click "Send me more information about Molluscs"
The last button should then display "Molluscs Grass Plants"

My html and javascript files
(I've indicated the part which I am fairly certain is not working properly)
(y[count].id should be the word "Grass", "Molluscs", or "Sweaters")
(infoChosen is the 4th and final button on the page)

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  for (count = 0; count < y.length; count++) {
    if (y[count].id == "infoChosen") {
      y[count].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("infoChosen").innerHTML = "";
        if (sessionStorage["Molluscs"] == "true") {
          document.getElementById("infoChosen").innerHTML += "Green Molluscs\n";
        }
        if (sessionStorage["Sweaters"] == "true") {
          document.getElementById("infoChosen").innerHTML += "Green Sweaters\n";
        }
        if (sessionStorage["Grass"] == "true") {
          document.getElementById("infoChosen").innerHTML += "Grass\n";
        }
        if (sessionStorage["Plants"] == "true") {
          document.getElementById("infoChosen").innerHTML += "Plants\n";
        }
      }
    } else {
      /////////////AREA OF THE CODE THATS NOT WORKING///////////////////////
      y[count].onclick = (function(z) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(z, "true");
      })(y[count].id);
      /////////////AREA OF THE CODE THATS NOT WORKING////////////////////////
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem(y[count].id, "false");
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem("Plants", "true");
}
```

```html
    <div><button id="Grass" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Grass</button></div>
  <div><button id="Molluscs" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Green Molluscs</button></div>
  <div><button id="Sweaters" type="button" class="button">Send me more information about Green Sweaters</button></div>
  <div><button id="infoChosen" type="button" class="button">Things you want more information about </button></div> 
  <div id="displayInfo"></div>
  <div><a href="otherPage.html">Other Page</a></div>
```

otherPage.html just contains

```
    <a href="example.html">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning event listeners by this:

```
y[count].onclick = (function(z) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(z, "true");
})(y[count].id);
```

Because **IIFE** (imediately invoked function expression) are imediately evaluated to their return value. Since they don't return anything, the `onclick` will be `undefined`. You should set up a closure then return a function that will be assigned to the `onclick` property like this:

```
y[count].onclick = (function(z) {
    return function() { // return a function reference to be assigned to the onclick
        sessionStorage.setItem(z, "true");
    };
})(y[count].id);
```

Comment: I made an edit to my code because I didn't realize the sessionStorage would reset once I switched webpages, I just added a link but I want the same things to come up when I switch pages and then when I come back

Comment: @Bob If you want your data to still be stored even after you closed the page or even shutdown you computer then use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage` as `sessionStorage` will be removed after the page is closed (session is lost), but `localStorage` will be kept there for as long as human will be on earth (metaphorically speaking) or untill the user clear his cache which will be equivalent to the end of the world (metaphorically speaking again)!

Comment: Here is the MDN docs for both [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) and [**sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/sessionStorage)!

Comment: Not after I've closed my page or shutdown my computer. I want it to be refreshed after that. I just want it to save while I navigate between links on the page. Once the window is close I want it to refresh

Comment: @Bob There isn't a middle solution, there is either `localStorage` that will stay there for as long as it could or `sessionStorage` that will be lost once the page is left. You can use `localStorage` and empty it once you've done with it or empty it on load so you get an empty space to fill.

Comment: I did what I'm talking about in some other code, but it was structured a bit differently, is there anyway I can post a zip file on here or send it you? @ibrahim mahrir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136207/discussion-between-bob-and-ibrahim-mahrir).